# The difference between dereferencing string instance variables and symbols in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with the **let** function in an rspec file. I wanted to use the **let** function to replace the use of string instance variables like I have used with @astr below.

```
describe "Static pages" do
  let (:str) { "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" }

 describe "Contact Page" do

it "should have title 'Contact'" do
    @astr = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  visit '/static_pages/contact'
  expect(page).to have_title("#{@astr} | Contact")
end
end

...
```

Which becomes

```
it "should have title 'Contact'" do
  visit '/static_pages/contact'
  expect(page).to have_title("#{str} | Contact")
end
```

What is confusing me is why **#{str}** works and **#{:str}** does not - dereference a symbol -, just as we keep the '@' for **#{@astr}**, why is the convention not applied to the colon in symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you defining `let(:str)...`, `str` become a method.

So, when you call `str` in test, you are not calling a variable, but a method which returns something you defined.

Three benefit of `let` over instance variables in my opinion.

1. It's more explicit.
2. It's lazy. The method won't return unless you call it. But a variable is always defined and lives in memory. So `let` is more efficient.
3. My own feeling only. `str`, as method, shows method color in my editor while instance variables show another. Method looks nicer and cleaner in my code.

Comment: Oh ok so 'str' becomes a method. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.